# PHPmailer send php generated by a while loop as body

Tags: php, email, while-loop, phpmailer

I have a while loop in my project that looks up and lists items (rows) from my database that the user has in their cart.

Using phpmailer body, what would be the best way to send the generated content?

`$m -> Body = "I want my different cart items to be echoed here";`

i have `$m -> isHTML(true);` on for any html i want to add.

The mail system i have works perfectly, but i want to be able to send the content that this generates (in this format if possible):

```
while($cart_item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch_cart_contents)){

$cart_item_list = $cart_item['product_id_list'];
$cart_corresponding_quantity = $cart_item['product_quantity_list'];
$cart_item_price = $cart_item['order_total'];

echo "<tr>
    <td>$cart_corresponding_quantity</td>
    <td>$cart_item_list</td>
    <td>$cart_item_price</td>
  </tr>";
}
```

P.s. I know how to concatenate variables with php, but this is my first time trying phpmailer, and  the while loop is throwing me off...

=========

Edit. So far i have

```
while($cart_item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch_cart_contents)){

$cart_item_list = $cart_item['product_id_list'];
$cart_corresponding_quantity = $cart_item['product_quantity_list'];
$cart_item_price = $cart_item['order_total'];

$emailbody .= "<tr>
    <td>$cart_corresponding_quantity</td>
    <td>$cart_item_list</td>
    <td>$cart_item_price</td>
  </tr>";
```

}

later in the document i do this to set the body.

`$m -> Body = "<h2>Order Details</h2><br>".$emailbody."<br><br>-- end of order --";`

Comment: Just append ( `$body .= "<tr>..."` ) instead of echo, and then after the loop set `$m->Body = $body`.

Comment: @Kenny The mail body is now showing up as blank. This was placed in the while loop. `$emailbody .= "<tr>
        <td>$cart_corresponding_quantity</td>
        <td>$cart_item_list</td>
        <td>$cart_item_price</td>
      </tr>";` does it look correct? I had the variable set as the body in the mail function correctly...

Comment: Could you update the question with those changes? Are you use you set the `$m->Body` after the loop? You could also do `$m->Body = ""; while(...){ ... $m->Body .= "<tr...";}`.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it now!!! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

As @Kenney said,

```
    $emailbody .= "<tr>
    <td>$cart_corresponding_quantity</td>
    <td>$cart_item_list</td>
    <td>$cart_item_price</td>
  </tr>";
```

concatenate the new items inside of the while loop and set the message body equal to `$emailbody`

Answer (score 0):

You have to first declare the value of `$emailbody`. The following should be sufficient.

```
    $emailbody = '';
    $emailbody .= "<tr>
       <td>$cart_corresponding_quantity</td>
       <td>$cart_item_list</td>
       <td>$cart_item_price</td>
    </tr>";
```